# Why HTML5 video tag is not working when src is dynamic using jQuery in bootstrap 4 modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML5 video URL when I click on it then open a bootstrap 4 modal with the same HTML 5 video URL but it's not working.

But when I make it static(direct path in modal) then it's working.

What I tried:-

```js
   
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.videoListUrl').click(function () {
               var videoTitle = $(this).find('.videoTitle').text();
               var videoUrl = $(this).find('.videoUrl').text();
               $('#videoModal').find('.modal-title').text(videoTitle);
               $('#videoModal').find('#paidVideos').find('source').attr('src', videoUrl);
               $('#videoModal').modal('show');
 });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div class="videoListUrl">
                          
                                   <div class="videoUrl">https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4</div>
                              
                       </div>
         
         
 
    <div class="modal" id="videoModal">
       <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
           <div class="modal-content">

               <!-- Modal Header -->
               <div class="modal-header">
                   <h4 class="modal-title"><%=dsCourseDetail.Tables[0].Rows[i]["VideoTitle"].ToString()%></h4>
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               </div>

               <!-- Modal body -->
               <div class="modal-body">
                   <div class="primary-video">

                       <video id="paidVideos"  width="400" controls="controls">
                           <source src="" />
                       </video>

                   </div>
               </div>

           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

The answer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below snippet, dynamically adding video url to video tag.

```js
$('.videoListUrl').click(function () {
    var videoTitle = $(this).find('.videoTitle').text();
    var videoUrl = $(this).find('.videoUrl').text().trim();
    $('#videoModal').find('.modal-title').text(videoTitle);
        
    var video = document.getElementById('paidVideos');
    var source = document.createElement('source');
    source.setAttribute('src', videoUrl);

    video.appendChild(source);
    video.play();
        
    $('#videoModal').modal('show');
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="videoListUrl">
 <div class="videoUrl">https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4</div>
</div>
        
    <div class="modal" id="videoModal">
       <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
           <div class="modal-content">

               <!-- Modal Header -->
               <div class="modal-header">
                   <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               </div>

               <!-- Modal body -->
               <div class="modal-body">
                   <div class="primary-video">

                       <video id="paidVideos" width="400" controls="controls">
                       </video>

                   </div>
               </div>

           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery is a bit wrong:

```
var videoTitle = $(this).find('.videoTitle').text();
var videoUrl = $(this).find('.videoUrl').text();
```

should have been:

```
var videoTitle = $('.videoTitle').text();
var videoUrl = $('.videoUrl').text();
```

now we are getting url to modal:
[image]
and not playing issue is about the buffer I guess. When you pass the src it is somehowe late. And why would you want to pass a src to modal?

This is a great [example](https://codepen.io/hennysmafter/pen/YqmLKR) I guess you would love to take a look which is I am assuming what you are trying.